# バイナリファイル(？)を、テキストエディタで閲覧できるように変換できますか？

Tags: windows, バイナリファイル

**質問**
データを独自形式の拡張子でファイル出力するWindowsソフトウェアがあります。
専用アプリケーションによる読込が前提だと思いますが、この独自拡張子のファイルを、テキストエディタで読み込む方法はありますか？
※そのまま読み込むと文字化けします。

**試してみたこと**
[「Binary_To_Text.js」](https://itbyari.wordpress.com/2015/12/25/windows-%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A8%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AA%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E7%9B%B8%E4%BA%92%E5%A4%89/)を作成して、ドラックアンドドロップしてみましたが、反応ありませんでした。

**やりたいこと**
出力ファイル内のデータをテキストファイルへコピペして、必要部分だけ取り出したいです。
※アプリケーション上にデータは表示されるのですが、コピペできません。

Comment: バイナリファイルを閲覧して、何をするのでしょうか？　バイナリファイルには、そのままでは文字として表現できない(文字コードではない)データが含まれています。それを読もうとする目的は何なのでしょうか？　それを質問で説明すると、適切な回答をもらえるかもしれません。

Comment: 「アプリケーション上にデータは表示されるのですが」と書かれていますが、そのアプリケーションとは何ですか？

Comment: やりたいことは「アプリケーション上に表示されたデータ」をコピペして、必要部分だけ加工してテキストデータとして使用することです。アプリケーションは「ShowOfflineFiles」と「FINALDATA フォトリカバリー9.0 無料体験版」です。

Comment: アプリケーションに表示されるのは、バイナリファイルの内容なのですか？　バイナリファイルはテキストファイルではないので、文字にできないデータが多く含まれていると思いますが、それらはどのように表示されるのですか？　１６進数の羅列ですか？

Comment: バイナリファイルをアプリケーションで読み込むと文字が表示されます(クリップボードコピーはできない)。バイナリファイルをアプリケーション以外で読み込む(あるいは変換する)ことにより文字をテキストデータとして取得できるのでは？ と思い質問しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのソフトウェアがどのようなデータ構造のファイルを作るかによります。
たとえばWordやEXCEL等のWindows Office製品はZip圧縮されたXMLファイル形式で持っているので、無理やり解凍すればデータが見れたりします。

単にテキストデータをバイナリ化しただけであれば簡単に読み出せますが
どういう構造のデータかはソフトウェアによるとしか言いようがありません。
（単純なテキストデータであればメモ帳に貼るなり、バイナリエディタで見えます）

Answer (score 1):

通常はバイナリエディタの使用を推奨しますが、Windows 向けテキストエディタの [EmEditor](https://jp.emeditor.com/) では [バイナリファイルの表示や編集](https://jp.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/more-features/binary-editing/) をすることもできます。

Comment: バイナリ(16進数表示)で開く、を選択すると、文字化けすることなく表示されました。ここから普通のテキストファイルとして表示させたいのですが…

Comment: cubick氏の回答の通りですがバイナリエディタを使うのがおすすめです WindowsならBinary Editor BZというのが有名だそうです

Answer (score 1):

"ShowOfflineFiles"は、以下に公開されているソフトでしょうか？
https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/dl/winnt/util/se521097.html
こちらはファイルの一覧をテキストとしてエクスポートする機能や、各種データをクリップボードにコピーする機能がありますが、これでは不十分ということでしょうか？
不十分な場合、それはどのようなものでしょうか？

Comment: はい。提示いただいたリンク先のソフトのことです。「不十分な場合、それはどのようなものでしょうか？」。「指定ディレクトリ」直下のファイルへ対して実行できるのですが、「指定ディレクトリ内にある全てのディレクトリ」へ対して、「指定ディレクトリ」を起点として実行したいです。

Comment: もう少し詳しく教えて下さい。すなわち、「指定ディレクトリ内にある全てのディレクトリ」にあるファイルの一覧をエクスポートしたいのでしょうか？

Comment: 自己紹介が遅れました、当該ソフトの作者です。
データはバイナリ化の際に圧縮されているため、テキストエディタでは見ることができません。今回の質問にで実現したい機能は、本ソフトに有用だと思ったのでソフトに追加しようと思います。
そこで、追加で質問です。エクスポートしたいのは（パス＋）ファイル名だけでしょうか？それとも、ファイルサイズ等もエクスポートしたいのでしょうか？

Comment: 「指定ディレクトリ内にある全てのディレクトリ」にあるファイル名をテキストデータとして取得したいです(定期的にエクスポートできる機能がさらに良いのですが…)。ファイルサイズ等は不要です。そう思った理由 → 私は「ディレクトリ構成変更」を頻繁に行います。バックアップを取得していますが、諸事情により同期させていません。ハードディスク不具合で指定ディレクトリが読み込めなくなった際、その中にある(はずの)ファイル名さえ分かればバックアップから復元できるのに、ということが何回かありました。treeコマンドを定期実行すれば済む話かもしれませんが、ShowOfflineFilesの方が色々便利なため、こういった機能があれば便利だと思いました(しかし、本来のソフトウェアの使用用途とは異なるかもしれません…)

Comment: コメント書いた後に気が付いたのですが、「指定ディレクトリ内にある全てを定期的にエクスポート」は矛盾していますね。データ取得時点ではどのディレクトリが読み込めなくなるか分からないので。改めて整理すると、私があったらいいなと思う機能の順番としては、1「SaveFolderStructure.exeで取得済データへ対して、指定ディレクトリ内にある全てのファイル名を手動でエクスポート」。2.「指定ドライブ全体に対する SaveFolderStructure.exe」の定期実行(日毎など)です。

Comment: ファイルサイズ不要、了解しました。おっしゃられた動作は、ShowOfflieFilesおよびSaveFolderStructureをオプション付きで起動可能にして、データのエクスポート機能をつければ実現できそうですね。re9さん側では「Windowsのタスクスケジューラ機能でSaveFolderStructureを定期起動してセーブデータを作成後、ShowOfflineFilesをオプション付きで自動起動してデータをエクスポート」すれば所望の動作になりそうです。では、ソフトを更新してみます。

Comment: 「オプション付きで起動」出来ると、さらに便利になると思います。負担にならない範囲でご対応いただけると有難いです。更新を楽しみにしています

Comment: ソフトを更新しました。オプション機能およびサブフォルダを含むファイルエクスポート機能を追加しました。以下に更新版を置きました。 x64: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ugPAc8ml35cAkvvnHksX-eg_6X2A2Oq/view?usp=sharing x86 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rMAL5jprtIC9nAhOzIuy8R_Hgmo36kFn/view?usp=sharing Vectorへの更新依頼もかけました。Vectorは毎週水曜に更新らしいのでお急ぎの場合は上記から、急がない場合はVectorから水曜以降に入手してください。タスクスケジューラの使い方はすみませんがそちらで調べてください。

Comment: この度は、お忙しい中ご対応いただきまして、誠にありがとうございました。早速試してみたところ、期待通り動作しました。「SaveFolderStructure」コマンドライン起動は、ドライブ単位だけではなくフォルダ単位でも指定できるのですね。とても便利だと思いました。

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです。

Answer (score 0):

UNIX系OS向けに[`strings`](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_binutils/man1/strings.1.html)という、ファイル中の文字列っぽいものを抽出するコマンドがありますが、MicrosoftがWindows向けに似たようなコマンドを提供しているようです。

- https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/strings

手元にWindowsが無いので試せていませんが、利用方法は例えば[こちら](https://xtech.nikkei.com/it/article/COLUMN/20120601/399983/)などに記載されています。